# How can I programatically create and dial a VPN connection on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-programming, vpn

I've recently noticed that some iOS applications, such as the Astrill VPN Client, are able to create and dial VPN connections.  In this specific case they seem to be Cisco IPSEC connections.  I have not been able to locate any official Apple documentation on how to do this.  Can anyone please tell me how this is possible?

Please note that I know how to configure VPN connections manually.  The reason I want my application to do it is to provide an idiot proof and streamlined process for customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These iOS apps achieve this by installing a VPN dialling profile that contains a VPN On Demand setting for a specific network and then simply try to connect to an address on that network, which prompts iOS to establish the VPN connection.

VPN On Demand can only be enabled for the IPSec (Cisco) connection type.  You can create a dialling profile to do this using the iPhone Configuration Utility to see how it works.

Comment: can you please share how to connect to an address on that network and how to turn on the VPN from the application?

Comment: @rahulraj, take a look at [this tutorial](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/10/15/create-an-on-demand-vpn-connection-programmatically-in-ios-8/) for how to use the NetworkExtension framework introduced in iOS 8.0 to connect to a VPN on demand.